Unconditional Security: How Does Quantum Cryptography Affect It?
I've been reading a paper ( "Unconditional Security in Classical
Cryptography" Petr Štika ) on cryptographic security, and I encountered some confusion about the concept of "unconditional security."
The paper defines unconditional security as follows:

"Unconditional security – a cryptographic system is unconditionally secure if it is secure even in the case where an adversary has unlimited resources for solving a problem, e.g., breaking a cipher."

The author then mentions that there are still problems that cannot be solved in an unconditionally secure way. This statement seems contradictory to me. If a system is unconditionally secure, doesn't that imply it is secure even against adversaries with unlimited resources?
Could it be that the term "unconditionally secure" is being misused here? I thought that by definition, if something is unconditionally secure, it means that no amount of resources, including those provided by quantum computers, could break it.
Or, are there specific algorithms that are considered unconditionally secure but still might be vulnerable to certain methods, such as those involving quantum cryptography?
Here is the exact quote from the paper:

"Despite the power of quantum cryptography and computers, there are still problems which cannot be solved in an unconditionally secure way."

You can find the paper here.
I am not a cryptography expert and would appreciate any clarification on this matter.

One Time Pad proved to be unconditionally secure against classical and quantum adversaries. Thanks to Shor's period-finding algorithm, quantum computers can have an advantage in solving some problems like factoring and discrete logs. Grover's, on the other hand, can only provide quadratic speed up, so instead of AES-128 use AES-256 and done. As you can see, this doesn't break anything unconditionally secure...

The text seems very straight forward.
The Author claims that there are two types of Cryptography : (X) Classical Cryptography (Y) Quantum Cryptography
These will all use some "Cryptographic Primitives" : (1) Encryption (2) Digital Signature (3) Digital Pseudo-Signatures (4) Dozens More
According to the level of security provided , the various "Cryptographic Primitives" can be grouped into 4 Categories :
(A) "Unconditionally Secure" (B) Provably Secure (C) Computationally Secure (D) Secure
The Authors then claims that there are some "Cryptographic Primitives" which are not yet "Unconditionally Secure" :

Maybe somebody has mathematically proved that it is impossible.
-- [[ Maybe nobody can ever invent that algorithm ]]
Maybe somebody has mathematically proved that it is possible , without actually making the algorithm.
-- [[ Maybe nobody has invented that algorithm yet ]]

ADDENDUM :
The Author lists these "Cryptographic Primitives" which are not "Unconditionally Secure" at the moment :

Bit commitment
Digital signature
Byzantine agreement
Coin tossing
Oblivious transfer

That was ( might have been ) true in 2010 , not sure what the current status is.

Ultimately, I understand this as follows: In the sentence 'There are still problems which cannot be solved in an unconditionally secure way,' the term 'solved' indicates that it is not possible to find unconditionally secure solutions for these problems. In other words, it may not be feasible to solve or secure certain problems in a way that no attacker can ever succeed. What is meant here is that these problems cannot meet the standards of unconditional security. This suggests that current or future techniques for addressing these problems cannot be designed to achieve unconditional security.

((1)) Yes , "these problems cannot meet the standards of unconditional security" is right , though we should think in terms of "Problems" == "Cryptographic Primitives" ((2)) It is not certain that "suggests that current or future techniques for addressing these problems cannot be designed" : Somebody might invent such techniques later
